# How to get the Absolute PATH of any directory from a Relative path, inside a Makefile

Tags: linux, makefile

I am working on a Makefile present in some directory "DirA". I need the absolute path of another directory "DirB" which is at a different PATH. How can I obtain this inside a Makefile.

The below works with bash script, how to obtain the same in Makefile.

```
SRCDIR = ./../../somepath/DirB 
ABS_PATH=$(realpath $(DirB))
```

I also tried using ${CURDIR} :

```
ABS_PATH = "${CURDIR}/../../somepath/DirB"
```

But, this again is a relative path.